# How to put a polynomial through points

Tags: matlab

I want to find the quadratic that passes through this points (0,0) (pi,2.1) (pi,0);

And here is my code

```
x = [0 pi pi]';
V = fliplr(vander(x));  % or V = [x.^2 x x.^0] 
y = [0 2.1 0]';
c = V \ y
```

The error comes at line 4.

```
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.
```

The results are :

```
c =
     NaN
     Inf
    -Inf
```

I tried to replace pi with other numbers , and it works . So please someone if you can please help me .

Comment: Well, your matrix is singular (it has rank 1), so it has no inverse.

Comment: Do you know  what can i do , for making it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach only works to find polynomials that have the specified y values *at* the specified x value. And there can only be one y value per x value.

If you want to find a 2D curve passing through these points, you need to introduce a parameter, say t, and find separate formulas for the x and y coordinates, something like this:

```
t = 0:2;
x = [0 pi pi]';
y = [0 2.1 0]';
V = fliplr(vander(t'));
cx = V \ x
cy = V \ y
```

Comment: i just want to find the quadratic equation.

Comment: What does that even mean? There can be no quadratic equation such that `a*pi^2+b*pi+c==2.1` and at the same time `a*pi^2+b*pi+c==0`, since that would imply `2.1==0`. And that is exactly what you are trying to compute.

Comment: well , that is the point , my teacher gave it to me as an homework , and iv tried to do it .

Comment: Do you understand *why* it is impossible? I assume she wants to get you to the point where you do. (You can get quadratics through these three points, even infinitely many, but they won’t be quadratics in x. They will be rotated parabolas.)

Comment: haha any way i made an mistake :D.. x = [0 pi/2 pi]   and y = [0 1 0]